# Get the values from the slider in jQuery and save that value into one variable

Tags: jquery, slider

I created a slider using `html.<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="accountLup" value="0" min="0" max="365" data-highlight="true" />`.

I want to retrieve this value from the slider and save it into one variable. How could I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by value ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery ui slider as I assume you should use it.

```
// getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```

or via method

```
var selected_value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "value" );
```

".selector" is name of class assigned to element that you use as slider. For example:

```
<div class="selector"></div>
```

More you will find here

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value

Remember also to bind "slider" after document is ready.

```
$(function() {
$( ".selector" ).slider();
$("#button_to_show_value").click(function (){
     alert($( ".selector" ).slider( "value" ));
  });
});
```

to show value after clicking button

```
<input type="button" id="button_to_show_value" value="click to show value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var YourVariable = $( "#sliderId" ).slider( "value" );
```

Read more about slider : [Here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker)

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value